# use of unconstructed message 'msg_mymessage'

Tags: biztalk

I have a BizTalk orchestration with an expression.  The expression has the following:

```
construct msg_mymessage { msg_mymessage = msgInputXML; }
```

msgInputXML and msg_mymessage use the same schema, same message type and both show up under the Messages in Orchestration view.

After the expression I have a Construct Message and in the Construct message I have a Transform that uses msg_mymessage as a source and some other message as a destination.

I'm getting the errors:
use of unconstructed message 'msg_mymessage'
'msg_mymessage':message has not been initialized in construct statement

I'm not sure why I get this error.  What should I be looking for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that you use an assignment shape (inside a construct message wrapper) when you create msg_mymessage. Then just copy the code in the expression shape (msg_mymessage = msgInputXML;)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee253499(v=bts.10).aspx

Comment: Thank you.  This fixed the build errors.  I'm not sure how I got the error because all I did was switch out the schema.  Before the schema switch it would build fine then after the switch it would no longer build until I put in the assignment shape.  Now to see if it still does what it's supposed to do...

Answer (score 1):

Do you need to do,

```
msg_mymessage = new System.Xml.XmlDocument();
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you didn't construct  `msg_mymessage` in earlier shapes.

Check the blog article [*Constructing BizTalk 2004 XML Messages (In an Orchestration) - Choices*](http://blogs.objectsharp.com/post/2004/11/09/Constructing-BizTalk-2004-XML-Messages-%28In-an-Orchestration%29-Choices.aspx) which demonstrates several ways to construct a message in BizTalk .

Answer (score 0):

In your constructed messages shape, you need to define the message type you are going to create.  when you drop the shape, the drop down dialog will ask you what type of message you are constructing.  You can select more than one.  so if you happen to have a message checked that isnt being constructed in this shape, you will get this exact message also.